# 2D Word Search Implementation: Getting index out of range exception (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, search, depth-first-search

I am trying to come up with a DFS Java solution for a 2D word search - I am checking a 2D char array to see if a word exists (allowed to move vertically and horizontally). When I am doing the bounds check for my recursive function, "findLetters", I'm getting an "index out of bounds" exception. I believe I set the bounds check correctly, so I'm not sure why its getting out of range.

Any ideas are appreciated!

**Test Case:**

```
char [][] board =
{
  {'A','B','C','E'},
  {'S','F','C','S'},
  {'A','D','E','E'}
};
```

> Given word = "ABCCED", return true. Given word = "SEE", return true.
>   Given word = "ABCB", return false.

**Error Message/Stack Trace:**

> Runtime Error Message: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   1     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:615)     at
>   Solution.findLetters(Solution.java:20)    at
>   Solution.exist(Solution.java:10)  at
>   **DriverSolution**.**helper**(**Driver**.java:8)  at **Driver**.main(**Driver**.java:54) Last executed input: [["a"]] "a"

**Solution:**

```
public boolean exist(char[][] board, String word) {

int row = board.length, column = board[0].length;

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {

        if (board[i][j] == word.charAt(0)) {
            if (findLetters(board, i, j, word, 1)) return true;
        }

    }
}     
return false;
}

public boolean findLetters(char[][] board, int i, int j, String word, int index) {

if (i < 0 || i >= board.length || j < 0 || j >= board[0].length || word.charAt(index) != board[i][j]) {
    return false;
}

    if (index == word.length()) return true;

    else if (
    findLetters(board, i + 1, j, word, index++) ||
    findLetters(board, i - 1, j, word, index++) ||
    findLetters(board, i, j + 1, word, index++) ||
    findLetters(board, i, j - 1, word, index++)
    )   {
        return true;
    }

return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Huh, it's too complicated to fix a recursive function without known expected input and output pairs - please provide few examples.

Comment: Have you tried running this through a debugger?

Comment: To add to Nikolas's comment, even if it were clear, your bounds check looks wrong to me since board.length will give you a 1-based index but the actual indices are 0-based. In other words, are you sure the bounds check shouldn't be like `i < 0 || i > board.length - 1` ...

Comment: Notice that word.charAt(index) can also throw  "index out of bounds" exception (https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-charat-method) - check if index < word.length()

Comment: Please post [mcve] including test data

Comment: And when asking about an exception, **always** post the complete and exact stack trace of the exception. It tells you exactly what the exception is, and where it's thrown.

Comment: You are Incrementing index 4 times : `findLetters(board, i, j - 1, word, index++)`  . Shouldn't it be done once ?

Comment: Yup!  They want `index+1`.  Incrementing index 4 times will cause `word.chatAt(index)` to IOOBE as the search approaches the end of the word.

Comment: Also `if (index == word.length()) return true;` should be before `word.charAt(index)`